# Debian hangs entering single user mode

Tags: debian, boot, data-recovery

My Debian system hangs when trying to enter single user mode on "start job is running for LSB" as shown in screenshot below. Any idea how to recovery it?

This thing started occurring after restarting system after installation of Nginx from mainline repositories.

This machine is VPS and can be accessed only by this recovery console.

[image]

Debian 8.3 Jessie 4.3.3-7~bpo8+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `init=/bin/bash` after `linux` line in grub and then removing fault script in `/etc/init.d`.

I also had to remount filesystem using `mount -o rw,remount /`.

And finally I booted to system using `exec init`.